# Phoenix framework & Ecto map field

Tags: phoenix-framework

Im have  :map field "groups" in my ecto model and im need to insert some data into it.

Example: Im have some user info like: username: "tester", group: "default" etc.

After saving in database, "groups" field should looks like:

```
[{username: "tester", group: "default"}, {username: "tester1", group: "admin"} etc...]
```

Also how i can modify data of this field in feature (When i'll need to add some additional records for example)?

Comment: Did you mean a list of maps like `[{username: ..., group: ...}, {username: ..., group: ...}]`? Your current example value is invalid.

Comment: yes, edited. thank you

Comment: Can you please also include the `field :groups, ...` declaration you're using in your model? and which database are you using? PostgreSQL?

Comment: Im using PostreSQL, in my model declaration im have only:... schema "permissions" do field :groups, :map end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[embeds_many/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#embeds_many/3)**

Here is the sample solution for you

```
defmodule MyApp.UserGroup do
  use Ecto.Schema

  embedded_schema do
    field :username
    field :group 
  end
end
```

you can add it with embeds_many your schema

```
defmodule MyApp.Group do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "groups" do
    embeds_many :usergroups, MyApp.UserGroup
    timestamps
  end
end
```

Let’s create a Group

```
changeset = Ecto.Changeset.change(%Group{})
            |> Ecto.Changeset.put_embed(:usergroups, [
               {username: "tester", group: "default"}, 
               {username: "tester1", group: "admin"}])

group = Repo.insert!(changeset)
```

you can work with user groups as a collection and then just put it as a change again & you can find details in [this blog post](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/08/working-with-ecto-associations-and-embeds/)